# CDH Community Edition Rolling Upgrade from 5.7 to 5.13

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

Can someone let me know how can I perform Rolling Upgrade of CDH from 5.7 to 5.13? I could not find much in Cloudera documentation regarding rolling upgrade of CDH Community Edition?

**EDIT**

As per the discussion below I can do upgrades manually stopping, upgrading (via "1 Click Install" )and starting the nodes. In a cluster like below

1. 3 Hbase Master (1 Active & 2 standby)
2. 4 Region Servers
3. 4 Data Nodes
4. 1 Primary & 1 Secondary Name Node
5. 3 Journal Node
6. 4 Nodemanager
7. 3 Resource Manager (1 Active & 2 standby)

What should be the order of stopping, upgrading & starting of components? Is it like below:-

1. Stop, Upgrade & Start all data nodes one by one.
2. Stop, Upgrade & Start region servers one by one
3. Stop, Upgrade & Start Upgrade HBase standby nodes one by one
4. Stop, Upgrade & Start Secondary Name Node
5. Upgrade Primary Name Node
6. Upgrade Journal Nodes
7. Upgrade HBase Master
8. Stop, upgrade & Start standby Resource Manager one by one
9. Stop, upgrade & Start Active Resource Manager
10. Stop, Upgrade & Start Nodemanagers one by one.

If I don't follow any order and update the services in the nodes in parallel, will I face any issue (as this is just a minor version upgrade)?

If I am taking the entire cluster down by stopping all the services in all the nodes and upgrading and then starting? What order should I follow while starting the services?

Comment: Start reading at least the 5.8 documentation. https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cm_ag_upgrading_cm.html

Comment: Rolling upgrade docs are here, and it's only available for Enterprise Licenses ... https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cm_mc_rolling_upgrade.html#cmug_topic_7_12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do it manually since you are using Community Version.

> A rolling upgrade allows you to upgrade your cluster software and
>   restart the upgraded services without taking the cluster offline.
>   Performing a rolling upgrade requires the following:
>
> - CDH was installed using Cloudera Manager and parcels. You can migrate your cluster from using packages to using parcels.
> - The cluster **uses a Cloudera Enterprise license**.

The [upgrade overview page](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_ag_upgrading_cm.html) has the information you need, but it generally follows

1. Backup Cloudera Manager database
2. Upgrade Cloudera Manager server
3. Upgrade Cloudera Manager Agents on all hosts
4. Upgrade CDH parcels
5. Reboot cluster. Try to do it per service. For example, make sure all Cloudera agents are healthly before starting Hadoop services. Then start the namenode(s), and datanodes, followed by resourcemanager(s), etc.

If you are not using Cloudera Manager, you will have to go through the command line upgrade procedures.

- [Before Upgrading to the Latest Release of CDH](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_upgrade_prereq2.html)
- [Upgrade CDH to latest](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_upgrade_to_latest.html)

From those you listed, you would stop all services before doing anything. For example, HBase isn't going to work if the datanodes and namenodes are down.

Build a dependency tree, and shut it down from the most dependent services. Meaning, HBase off, then YARN (one resource manager at a time), then HDFS (datanodes, then namenodes and journalnodes). Then upgrade and start them in reverse order.

---

The second link there says this order for upgrades

- NameNode into safemode
- Stop all Hadoop services
- Backup the namenode
- Download the 1-click packages
- Upgrade YARN (which requires upgrading Zookeeper)
- Upgrade JournalNodes
- Start HDFS Service
- Start YARN
- Upgrade rest of components

Comment: How can I do manually without Cloudera Manager as I am using community version? Is there any place I can check the steps? In cloudera doc I am not able to find the manual upgrade steps.

Comment: There's a link in my post... You can still use Cloudera Manager to manage parcels, yes?

Comment: Also, how did you install Cloudera Manager to begin with? The procedure is not much different. You download the new version, and set it up. Then you will also need to upgrade the agents to be able to communicate with the new manager. I'm sure the Cloudera Support Forums are a better place to ask for this information in detail.

Comment: I did not install Cloudera Manager as it needs License. I just installed the CDH components manually.

Comment: Theres a link for non-Cloudera Manager installs there too... https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_upgrade_5_to_latest.html#xd_583c10bfdbd326ba--6eed2fb8-14349d04bee--77b0 Also, FWIW, Cloudera Express does not require a license. https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_ig_non_production.html#concept_p25_ttb_vbb

Comment: Rolling upgrade is not supported in cloudera express http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/manager/5-1-x/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cm5ig_feature_differences.html

Comment: Yes, I never said it was. **Rolling** upgrade isn't available, but that doesn't mean you can't upgrade the services, and "roll" them yourself.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "Rolling"? Can I just stop services in one node , upgrade the package in the node via "1-Click-Install", start the node, and repeat the process in other nodes one by one ? Will this work or there are some nuances?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean, roughly. Though, you'll want to stop all the services before you bring them back online. Also, for the namenode and resourcemanagers, or zookeeper servers (if you are using a high-availability cluster), when you stop those, the entire cluster is basically offline anyway

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with last set of queries after discussion with you. Can you please edit your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: In the second link when do I have to leave the safe mode for Namenode or it will be auto exited ?

Comment: It will probably leave safemode during the "Start HDFS Service" stage, but you'll need to double check that from the NameNode UI

Comment: The underlying versions of hadoop & hbase components have not changed in 5.7 & 5.13. So can I just upgrade the services in any random order? For example let's say I have upgraded the Secondary Name Node and some data node to the latest 5.13. Will the updated node will be able to talk with the old 5.7 ? Is the latest 5.13 fully backward compatible with 5.7? Cluster downtime is not an issue but eventually when all the node is updated will the cluster be fine.

Comment: The above question may sound little weird but in summary I am asking this because the legacy set-up in which I am working right now does not have any centralized mechanism to control upgrade secondary NN first then primary & so on.

Comment: The component versions might not have changed, but the packages might include some code patches

Comment: For example, `hbase-1.2.0+cdh5.7.6+208` vs `hbase-1.2.0+cdh5.13.0+411`... That last number means the number of patches applied